# How to find start of 3 months before today in Java?

Tags: java, date

```
final Calendar tentativeStartDate =  Calendar.getInstance();
    tentativeStartDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    tentativeStartDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    tentativeStartDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    tentativeStartDate.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    tentativeStartDate.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    tentativeStartDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
```

I want start of 3 months prior to current month. eg if today is june 18, i want midnight April 1 at 0 mins/seconds. [ April 1st, 00:00:00 ]

But this logic is not giving me the right answer. Is there a better/different way in Java ?

Comment: Did you try it out? Or do you have an issue with your solution?

Comment: Actually I don't understand your question

Comment: This code return 01 March and it works correctly

Comment: march was 3 months ago. I don't know why you think this is a problem

Comment: He probably asks is this a good way to find a date 3 months before

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Java 8, you can use a fluent idiom as follows:

**Zoned**

```
ZonedDateTime.now([your zone ID, e.g. ZoneId.systemDefault()])
    // month offset
    .minusMonths(2)
    // start at day 1
    .withDayOfMonth(1)
    // change time-of-day to when the day starts
    .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
```

**Local**

```
LocalDate.now([your zone ID, e.g. ZoneId.systemDefault()])
    .minusMonths(2)
    .withDayOfMonth(1)
```

**Note**

I set the month offset to `2` since you want April.

Comment: Good Answer. FYI to the reader: If you really need only the date without a time-of-day, use `LocalDate` with similar method calls as seen here.

Comment: @BasilBourque good point - wrote the local date part a little too fast! Fixed now.